# How to use regex in PHP to get int after slash in string

Tags: php, regex

I've tried to create a code in PHP that gets the topic id after the forward slash in a given string. However the problem i'm having is that its returning nothing, how can i make it return the int?

```
echo  preg_match('/([^/]+)/', 'Learning-English/478', $discussion_id);
echo $discussion_id;
```

This is for an online forum, thank you for your help; it's much appreciated. If you need ay more information please don't hesitate to leave a comment.

Comment: `([^/]+)/', 'Learning-English/(\d+)` should do. Where `(\d+)` matches one digit or more and will be put in to a match group.

Comment: What does your string looks like? Maybe you don't need a regex.

Comment: string is anything  then a forward slash then an integer

Comment: You can also just explode it then `explode('/', $string)[1]`

Comment: Why not split the string and get the last element? It is way faster than regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("#/(\d+)$#", 'Learning-English/478', $discussion_id);
```

That would work for you.

To print the `id`(matched number); you need to echo `$discussion_id[1]`.

Here is a working [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/S5pOV9).

---

For the newer strings, you wouldn't be needing the string end match(`$`). Thus, the regex will be:

```
preg_match("#/(\d+)#", 'Looking-for-Pen-Pals/1161&t=viewDiscussion', $discussion_id);
echo $discussion_id[1];
```

Comment: @Allendar **topic id after the forward slash** is what OP wants.

Comment: i tried this but it catched everything after the forward slash, i just want the into, may have more characters after

Comment: @JakeStainer Can you please post some more example strings that you have?

Comment: Looking-for-Pen-Pals/1161&t=viewDiscussion

Comment: @JakeStainer Check the difference.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use `explode()` like this:

```
$arr = explode('/',$string);
$discussion_id = $arr[count($arr)-1];
```

this will split your string and then get you the last part.